# Mongo DB-adding Json object to existing document without creating a new entry(not an array)

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a Json object in my mongodb that is already inserted.

```
 {
    "appname":"abcd",
    "appId":"E3456",
    "modules":{
      "sales":{
         "apis":{
            "get all sales":{
               "method":"get",
               "access_ctrl_level":"admin",
               "req_fields":[

               ],
               "url":"url_to_api",
               "error_code":[
                  {
                     "code":502,
                     "desc":"no authentication"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Now I want to add another object to "sales.apis".

```
 "get sales details":{
               "method":"get",
               "access_ctrl_level":"admin",
               "req_fields":[
                  "saleNo"
               ],
               "url":"url",
               "error_code":[
                  {
                     "code":502,
                     "desc":"no authentication"
                  }
               ]
            }
```

I used below code to find and modify the document to insert this new object into collection

```
db.MetaData.findAndModify({query: { $and:[{modules:{sales:{apis:{"get all sales":{method:"get"}}}}},{"appname":"erp"}] },
    update: {$set:{modules:{sales:{apis:{"get sales details":{method:"post","access_ctrl_level":"admin","url":"url"}}}}}},
    upsert: true
})
```

But this is creating new entry in MetaData document. But I want to insert this under "modules.apis.get sales details" in the same document
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to do it through [`dot notation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

> To access a field of an embedded document with `dot-notation`, concatenate the embedded document name with the `dot (.)` and the field name, and enclose in quotes:

```
findAndModify({
        query: { "modules.sales.apis.get all sales.method":"get", 
                 "appname":"erp"} ,
        update: {
               $set:{"modules.sales.apis.get sales details": 
                    {"method":"post",
                     "access_ctrl_level":"admin",
                     "url":"url"}}},
        upsert: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in your query, you typed wrong appName, I think you mean 'abcd' instead of 'erp'.

```
.findAndModify(
{
  "query": {
    "modules.sales.apis.get all sales.method": "get",
    "appname": "abcd"
  },
  "update": {
    "$set": {
      "modules.sales.apis.get sales details": {
        "method": "post",
        "access_ctrl_level": "admin",
        "url": "url"
      }
    }
  },
  "upsert": true
}
)
```