# Sending csv file from Node.js to MongoDB in the form of JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

I am sending csv file in the form of json object into mongodb. The problem is that if i have 1000 mcqs in my csv file then all mcqs are inserting at same time but i need to insert mcqs 100 by 100 so i dont know how to write its logic. Here is the code snippet.

```js
import csvtojson from "csvtojson";
import { DBCSV } from "./Db.js";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const DB_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://mern:MERN@cluster0.nmswu.mongodb.net/CsvRecords?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose
  .connect(DB_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log("db connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

csvtojson()
  .fromFile("MCQ.csv")
  .then((jsonObj) => {
    
    DBCSV.insertMany(jsonObj);
    // console.log(jsonObj);
  });
```

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837481/mongo-db-adding-json-object-to-existing-document-without-creating-a-new-entryno

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo DB-adding Json object to existing document without creating a new entry(not an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837481/mongo-db-adding-json-object-to-existing-document-without-creating-a-new-entryno)